# How can I dogfood an Expo debug app without it self-deleting?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use an Expo app day-to-day to test it.  It seems that the app just deletes itself from Expo Go from time to time - I assume when it is cycled out of memory.  I can also replicate this by killing Expo Go - my app disappears.

That means I have to fire up a developer server again just to use the app.

I believe the "development build" has the same issue since it's just a custom version of Expo Go.  How can I get a debug build (with debug menu and error messages) that will not get auto-deleted unpredictably?